# How to protect Word footnotes or endnotes from accidental deletion?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-office-2013, footnote, endnote

It's very easy when correcting a document to delete a footnote, since they are marked by small characters

It's easy to miss them and to delete a paragraph without noticing that at the same time a footnote is deleted.

Is there a way to get a warning in Word before deleting a footnote or endnote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way to protect the notes by changing how they are displayed: bigger number in red are much easier to spot.

To change how end or footnotes style:

1. go to home tab
2. clik on the little arrow bellow the style frame to popup the "style" widget
3. click on the little "manage tab" button on the bottom
4. in edit tab: "sort by alphabetical" and find the "footnotes
   references"
5. then customized its style to make it... unforgettable

Thanks to [that video tuto (4th video)](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Footnotes-in-Word-2013-eb4c92f1-dc07-4ebe-92a9-3326820e6142)